# No package.xml found : Trying to deploy the salesforce package using Rest API

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, deployment-api, deployment-error

I'm trying to deploy the unmanaged package to my salesforce developer account using the following doc from salesforce [Deploy Metadata with Apex Testing Using REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_rest_deploy.htm) As per the doc in body I'm passing zip as Base64 encoded string

While I was trying to deploy the same package from the workbench the package is getting deployed successfully.

[Postman Collection](https://www.getpostman.com/collections/fc193e57342aafa96612) please refer the saved responses

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! If you haven't read it yet, please take a moment to read about [ask]. That said, this is an exemplary first question; it had everything needed to quickly identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `singlePackage` flag, the `package.xml` must be at the *root* of the ZIP. Checking your file, the listing is `manifest/package.zip`, which won't work. Either turn off the `singlePackage` flag, or make sure the `package.xml` is at the root folder in the ZIP.